# Dual problem to rewrite

Tags: linear-programming, programming

I have this problem:
$$ \max -2p_1-4p_2$$
$$p_1 \leq 3$$
$$p_2 \leq 4$$
$$ p_1+p_2\geq 5$$
$$ -p_1-p_2\geq -5$$
$$p_1,p_2>0$$
The dual problem:
$$\min  \zeta = 3y_1+4y_2+5y_3-5y_4 $$
$$ubb  y_1+y_3-y_4\geq -2$$
$$ y_2+y_3-y_4\geq -4$$
$$y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\geq 0$$.
But the problem formulated in general is:
$$\max -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{I}c_ip_i$$
Ubb $$p_i\leq p_i^{max} \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{I} p_i \leq d \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$
$$-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{I} p_i \leq -d \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$
$$p_i\geq 0 \ \ \forall \ i\in\{1,2,...,I\}$$.
I have to formulate now the dual form for the LP problem generally, where we let $q_i$ be the dual variable back to the capacity limits for the production level of unit $i$ and let $q_0$ denote the dual variable
belong to the balance between supply and demand. How can I do that? Can someone help me. I have to find a transposing matrix I think?

Comment: There is a general formulation to find the dual form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program). It is not the right way to guess the general form from one specific example.

Comment: With [this table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249770/how-do-i-find-the-dual-of-the-lp/3249908#3249908) it is easy to transform a primal problem into a dual problem.